# Updating a Typeahead local resultset

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, typeahead

Ok, this is a difficult one. I am, atm, just hacking into infinite at [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js), can someone please give me some better pointers..

What I want to create is a dropdown typeahead with results from an array. The array always changes, but it changes slowly and with lots of delays. So the typeahead dropdown should update whenever the user puts some text in (i got that to work), but also when the array is updated externally.

Updating the array is actually done in a single function, and it's really easy to add some code to update the typeahead dropdown, but I dont know how !

Code:

```
//The local array that should be searched within. It contains records {strTitle: '..', strCategory: '..'}
var arrSearchResults = [];

//The Typeahead definition..
$('#txtNavbarSearch').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'strTitle',
  source: function(strSearchQuery, fncCallback) {
    fncCallback(arrSearchResults);
  }
});

//Function that is invoked in existing code
function fncUpdateSearchResults(arrAddResults) {

  //Add some code here to update the typeahead dropdown..??

  $.each(arrAddResults, function(strKey, arrResult) {
    arrSearchResults.push(arrResult);
  });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Example how you can update source:

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead" />
```

```
var b = $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: ["Alabama", "Montana"]
});

setTimeout(function(){
    b.data('typeahead').source = ["Another", "USA", "BLUR"];
    $(".typeahead").trigger('blur').val("").focus();
}, 5000);
```

So you can see my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DvEcx/)

Comment: At five seconds (good), the data is changed (good), but the script empties the textbox (not good), and the dropdown also disappears (because the text is empty) (not good)...

Comment: For example user types some text "Alab" we have one variant "Alabama",
after 5 seconds we have new data without "Alabama" what we can do?

Comment: Correct, what do we do then? The dropdown needs to be re-rendered automatically when there is new data

Comment: Do you see selectize.js library?